# Why is rstrip() not removing trailing whitespace?

Tags: python

rstrip isn't removing the whitespace at the end of a string as expected.

```
n=open("negative.txt","r")
negative=[]
for line in n:
    line.rstrip()
    negative.append(line)
```

```
print(negative[0])
```

yields GGT...AAG (don't want to bother typing it all)

```
print(len(negative[0]))
```

yields 42

```
print(negative[0][40])
```

yields G

```
print(negative[0][41])
```

yields a blank line

Why didn't rstrip get rid of the trailing whitespace?

Comment: The `rstrip` method *returns* a stripped string, it doesn't modify it in place (because strings are immutable objects). Try `line = line.rstrip()` or do it all on one line with `negative.append(line.rstrip())`.

Comment: By the way, this can be done as `negative = n.read().splitlines()`

Answer (score 2):

`rstrip()` returns a right stripped string. It is not in place.

You want:

```
line = line.rstrip()
```